# Часть ImageView не отображается на экране при перемещении

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Не могу понять в чем дело. Есть RelativeLayout(match_parent,match_parent) в нем ImageView с конкретными размерами 100 на 100 например и размещен в центре слоя. Обрабатываю перемещение его пальцем по экрану. Он нормально перемещается, но не вверх, вверху линия, за пределами которой он не прорисовывается. Эта линия как раз проходит по верхней границе ImageView в начальном положении.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cameraLayout">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewWounds"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewZoomOut"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom_out"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewZoomIn"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom_in"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTake"
            android:src="@drawable/take"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRotateLeft"
            android:src="@drawable/rotate_left"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewTake"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTake"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_button_take"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRotateRight"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewRotateLeft"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewRotateLeft"
            android:src="@drawable/rotate_right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Проблемный - imageViewWounds. Сейчас стоят размеры по контенту, но ставил и фиксированные, без изменений.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос файл с разметкой

Comment: @ZigZag Разметку добавил

Comment: @Fox, а если SurfaceView убрать? Может в нём проблема... Так-то в разметке всё норм, вроде...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да. проблема в нем, но он мне нужен для отображения превью с камеры... 
решение нашлось, но довольно странное... я поставил в левый верхний угол экрана imageView 1 пиксель.. и он начал все отрисовывать.... возможно, система в целях экономии ресурсов специально не рисует все, выше уже существующей разметки, при обработке surfaceView

Comment: @Fox, наверное вы правы) Напишите это в качестве ответа на вопрос - возможно ещё кому-то пригодится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из способов решения проблемы - установка в верхний левый угол (можно и правый)) - любого View (ImageView например) в один пиксель, чтобы система принудительно все отрисовывала.